# Unexpected output of top when started by systemctl

Tags: linux, systemctl

I want to log the cpu and memory usage of a service which starts some time after startup (`webappmgr.service`). For this I have created another simple logging service which depends on it and shall be run after `webappmgr` starts called `perftrace.service`. This shall continuously write the output of `top` and `awk` to the file `/tmp/webapp.top`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Perftrace
After=webappmgr.service

[Service]
User=root
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'top -b -H -p $(pgrep webappmgr) | awk \'{ print strftime("%%H:%%M:%%S", systime())" " $0 }\' > /tmp/webapp.top &'

[Install]
WantedBy=webappmgr.service
```

When the system is started up and `webappmgr` is running, I start `perftrace` by `systemctl start perftrace`. In the file `/tmp/webapp.top` I see what I want to see:

```
04:26:27  2596 testuser  20   0 1887640  24092  17068 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.27 webappmgr
04:26:27  2622 testuser  20   0 1887640  24092  17068 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.06 JSEngine
04:26:27  2628 testuser  20   0 1887640  24092  17068 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.01 webappmgr
04:26:27  2629 testuser  20   0 1887640  24092  17068 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 webappmgr
04:26:27  2630 testuser  20   0 1887640  24092  17068 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 webappmgr
04:26:27  2631 testuser  20   0 1887640  24092  17068 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 webappmgr
04:26:27  2632 testuser  20   0 1887640  24092  17068 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 FileDownloa+
```

However, after enabling the `perftrace.service` and rebooting the system, so that it starts at the startup right after `webappmgr`, I see a completely different ouput in the file:

```
04:31:03 %Cpu(s): 33.1 us, 17.7 sy,  0.1 ni, 41.2 id,  1.2 wa,  4.3 hi,  2.5 si,  0.0 st
04:31:03 KiB Mem :  4667484 total,  1369968 free,  2187548 used,  1109968 buff/cache
04:31:03 KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  2373988 avail Mem
04:31:03
04:31:06   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
04:31:06
04:31:06 top - 04:31:06 up 1 min,  1 user,  load average: 40.87, 12.93, 4.54
04:31:06 Threads:   0 total,   0 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
04:31:06 %Cpu(s): 11.2 us, 15.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 66.8 id,  0.8 wa,  3.5 hi,  2.1 si,  0.0 st
04:31:06 KiB Mem :  4667484 total,  1362788 free,  2194416 used,  1110280 buff/cache
04:31:06 KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  2367116 avail Mem
04:31:06
04:31:09   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
04:31:09
04:31:09 top - 04:31:09 up 1 min,  1 user,  load average: 40.87, 12.93, 4.54
04:31:09 Threads:   0 total,   0 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
04:31:09 %Cpu(s): 11.9 us, 16.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 66.0 id,  0.0 wa,  3.6 hi,  2.2 si,  0.0 st
04:31:09 KiB Mem :  4667484 total,  1358060 free,  2199204 used,  1110220 buff/cache
04:31:09 KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  2362388 avail Mem
04:31:09
```

what shall I do to get similar output to when I started my perftrace service manually?

Comment: I worked around this issue by modifying the `ExecStart` to start a script which would call `top -b -n 1  ...` in a while-true loop, with a little pause in between.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Thanks, I reposted it.